# Share async data between controllers without making multiple requests

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm trying to make a single `$http` request to get one of my JSON files and use the data across all my controllers.

I saw on egghead.io how to share data across multiple controllers, and I've also read this StackOverflow question: "[Sharing a variable between controllers in angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508666/sharing-a-variable-between-controllers-in-angular-js)".

However, the answers there don't use the `$http` module. When using `$http`, the controllers don't have the data to work on, and by the time the response is received it's already too late.

I then found the method `$q.defer` and this question on StackOverflow: "[AngularJS share asynchronous service data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125076/angularjs-share-asynchronous-service-data-between-controllers)"

The solution posted there works fine, BUT it has two issues:

1. Each controller will trigger the `$http` request to obtain the same data already used in another controller; and,
2. If I try to manipulate the data received I have a `then` function.

Below you can see my code:

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

function appInstallerListCtrl($scope, Data) {
  $scope.apps = Data;
}

function appInstallerDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Data) {
  $scope.appId = $routeParams.appId;
  $scope.apps = Data;  
  console.log($scope.apps); // <-- then function
  console.log(Data); // <-- then function with $vv data returned but I can't access it

  for (var i in $scope.apps) // <--- no way, baby!
    console.log(i);
}
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('appInstaller', []);

app.factory('Data', function($http, $q) {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  $http.get('apps.json').then(function(result) {
    defer.resolve(result.data.versions.version);
  });
  return defer.promise;
});

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/app', {templateUrl: 'partials/app-list.html',   controller: appInstallerListCtrl}).
    when('/app/:appId', {templateUrl: 'partials/app-detail.html', controller: appInstallerDetailCtrl}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/app'});
}]);
```

What I'd like to have is that when launching the app, the `$http` request will be performed and the response will be used throughout the app across all controllers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a promise, to access the data returned by promise use the callback syntax

```
function appInstallerDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Data) {
  $scope.appId = $routeParams.appId;
   Data.then(function(returnedData) {
        $scope.apps=returnedData;
        console.log($scope.apps);
        for (var i in $scope.apps)
           console.log(i)   
   });   
}
```

Make sure this

```
defer.resolve(result.data.versions.version);
```

resolve returns array, for the above code to work. Or else see what is there in data and ajust the controller code.

Comment: Thanks but the code is not correct. I get an error at: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { after the Data.then and there is still the ) bracket.

Comment: See the documentation on $q here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q , i just highlighted the basic idea. I have tried to fix my code too.

Comment: wow it works! thank you very much and I'll check out the doc you highlighted.

Answer (score 14):

I like to store my data in the service, and return a promise to the controllers, because usually you need to deal with any errors there.

```
app.factory('Data', function($http, $q) {
   var data = [],
       lastRequestFailed = true,
       promise;
   return {
      getApps: function() {
         if(!promise || lastRequestFailed) {
            // $http returns a promise, so we don't need to create one with $q
            promise = $http.get('apps.json')
            .then(function(res) {
                lastRequestFailed = false;
                data = res.data;
                return data;
            }, function(res) {
                return $q.reject(res);
            });
         }
         return promise;
      }
   }
});

.controller('appInstallerListCtrl', ['$scope','Data',
function($scope, Data) {
    Data.getApps()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    }, function(res) {
        if(res.status === 500) {
            // server error, alert user somehow
        } else { 
            // probably deal with these errors differently
        }
    });
}]);
```

Any callbacks that are registered after a promise has been resolved/rejected will be resolved/rejected immediately with the same result/failure_reason.  Once resolved/rejected, a promise can't change (its state).  So the first controller to call `getApps()` will create the promise.  Any other controllers that call `getApps()` will immediately get the promise returned instead.

Comment: +1, this is (i think) the finest practice for sync large app.

Thank, and as often on stackoverflow, your right :)

Comment: Binding to promises doesn't work in the newer versions(1.2+ i think). Use Data.getApps().then(function(result){//save result here in $scope})

Comment: @shrutyzet, thanks.  I finally got around to updating my answer.

Comment: But if u run Data.getApps().then(function(data) { .. }); multiple times, you get multiple GET requests. How to stick with only one request?

Comment: @Anze, only one GET request should be sent.  Additional calls to getApps() should simply return the promise.

Comment: @MarkRajcok, on this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/vw4b09g7/3/) you can see two GET requests.

Comment: @Anze, I see. If you change the if statement to `if(!promise)` then you only get one GET request.  It seems that with two controllers, the promise gets resolved before `lastRequestFailed` is set, so this introduces a race condition.

Comment: @MarkRajcok how would you refresh this data when changing states in ui-router? It keeps the same data even when I load a different detail page since there isn't a page reload. Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 1):

I found the way not sure weather it is a best approach to do it or not.

In HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">{{user.title}}</div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl2">{{user.title}}</div>
</body>
```

In Javascript

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http, userService) {
      userService.getUser().then(function(user) {
        $scope.user = user;
      });
    });

   app.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, $http, userService) {
      userService.getUser().then(function(user) {
        $scope.user = user;
      });
    });

   app.factory('userService', function($http, $q) {
    var promise;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
      return {
        getUser: function() {
          if(!promise){     
          promise = $http({
              method: "GET",
              url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
            }).success(function(res) {
                data = res.data;
              deferred.resolve(res);
            })
            .error(function(err, status) {
              deferred.reject(err)
            });
          return deferred.promise;
          }
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    });
```

This will exactly make only 1 HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I didn't want to wait for `resolve` before loading another controller because it would show a "lag" between controllers if the network is slow. My working solution is passing a promise between controllers via `ui-router`'s `params` and the data from promise can be loaded asynchronously in the second controller as such:

**app.route.js** - setting the available params to be passed to SearchController, which shows the search results

```
        .state('search', {
            url: '/search',
            templateUrl: baseDir + 'search/templates/index.html',
            controller: 'SearchController',
            params: {
                searchPromise: null
            }
        })
```

**landing.controller.js** - controller where the user adds search input and submits

```
    let promise = SearchService.search(form);
    $state.go('search', {
        searchPromise: promise
    });
```

**search.service.js** - a service that returns a promise from the user input

```
    function search(params) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $timeout(function() {
                resolve([]) // mimic a slow query but illustrates a point
            }, 3000)
        })
    }
```

**search.controller.js** - where search controller

```
    let promise = $state.params.searchPromise;

    promise.then(r => {
        console.log('search result',r);
    })
```